# What is the probability of having $d$ duplicates when sampling $n$ elements from a pool of $N$ elements?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, sampling

**Question**

What is the probability $P(d | n,N)$ of having $d$ duplicates in my sample if I sample with replacement $n$ elements from a pool of $N$ elements?

**How to count duplicates?**

The number of duplicates is defined as the number of pairwise comparison that are the same. That is

$$d = \sum_i \sum_{j>i} f(x_i,x_j)$$

where

$$ 
f(x_i,x_j) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x_i = x_j$} \\
0, & \text{if $x_i ≠ x_j$}
\end{cases}$$

For example `[1,3,3,1]` has 2 duplicates. `[1,3,1,1]` has 3 duplicates. `[1,1,1,1]` has 6 duplicates and `[1,3,1,1,2,2,1,3]` has 8 duplicates.

**For $d$ equals 0**

I think it is correct that $P(d=0 | n,N) = \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} 1 - \frac{i}{N}$. But I could not go any further.

Comment: How do you count duplicates ? for instance $1,1,1,2,1,2$ how many duplicates does it contain ?

Comment: @GCab With this question, you totally nailed a big part of what prevented me to find an answer... I did not understand my own question.... I edited my post to clarify this point. Thank you

Comment: Yes, of course the definition of *duplicate* is critical to find an answer. Try and distinguish between *repetition* and *number of characters repeated two or more times*, etc.

Comment: @GCab Let me know if the question is still unclear to you

Comment: Good, now it is well clear!

Comment: The number of times of the $i$-th elements being sampled $X_i$ jointly follows a multinomial distribution, $i = 1, 2, \ldots, N$. For $X_i \geq 2$, the number of duplicates $D_i$ generated by this element is $\displaystyle D_i = \binom {X_i} {2} = \frac {X_i(X_i - 1)} {2}$ and when $X_i = 0, 1$, $D_i = 0$. So the formula $\displaystyle D_i = \frac {X_i(X_i - 1)} {2}$ holds. Then $\displaystyle D = \sum_{i=1}^N D_i = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac {X_i(X_i - 1)} {2} = \frac {1} {2} \left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^N X_i\right) = \frac {1} {2} \left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2 - n\right)$

Answer (score 2):

The number of duplicates is approximately Poisson distributed, with expectation parameter $\lambda= \binom n 2 / N$. In particular, if $n$ and $N$ go to infinity in such a way that $\binom n 2/N\to\lambda$, the number of duplicates converges in distribution to $\operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$.  This is an easy consequence of the "Chen-Stein" method, as described in many places.  The Chen-Stein method itself is too complex to sketch here, but is well described in a very readable  book *Poisson Approximation* by Barbour, Holst and Janson. Its application to the birthday problem is described in a [paper](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~tracy/courses/math135A/UsefullCourseMaterial/birthday.pdf).

Comment: interesting answer, can you argument more about ?

Comment: Not in the margin of this postcard.  This falls out of the results of a classical book, reviewed [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/Misc/barbour.pdf) giving an idea of what's going on.

Comment: See [example 7.2 in these lecture notes.](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~psdey/414CourseNotes.pdf).

Comment: Thanks(+1) especially because you made me catch the similiraty with birthday problem